What is the blue liquid dripping from outdoor unit of split type air-conditioner, and how to fix?
My mini-split air conditioner is newly installed.
The spec is using R32 refrigerant
Day 1, get installed;
Day 2, notice dripping and called the installation guy again.
Day 5, Install guys change the installation of the copper tube
Before the dripping is clear water, now it drips blue liquid.
I also collected a drop of the liquid, it stays in liquid form after 12 hours, but inside become cloudy.
What is the liquid actually, is there refrigerant leak?
The liquid stays in liquid form after putting in the bottle for 12 hours;
Is it possible that R32 became liquid form and leaks out?

residual on blade2
status after 2nd installation.3


Any of the known chemicals that are used in refrigeration and referred to as "Freon", boil and dissipate as a gas at a temperature far below ambient temperatures.
There are a few options for the blue liquid. Most likely it is an oil. Oil will not dry up as fast as water and when mixed with water often turns milky.
What you see is not freon , but possibly the oil which is carried with the freon throughout the system. Seeing this would indicate a leak and some freon is escaping. Or had escaped when the techs came back to address your first issue. ( dripping of water on the outside compressor/ condenser unit is normal. Especially in high humidity climates.)
It could be an oil that is sprayed on the components to keep them from oxidizing when being shipped and stored.
It could be a tracing agent, that again is sprayed on components to check for leaks. The color changes when it comes in contact with another chemical (freon)  to indicate a leak.
It could be a sealer for lines. However that would be located only by line connections to components, so not likely, but possible.
There could have been a mishap in manufacturing and components got covered in a mist of the oil (or whatever this is) and now the stuff is being washed off from condensation.
The Bottom line here is the system was just installed. Call the company that and tell them what you are seeing. They should have the definitive answer and act to correct the issue.  It could be a simple rinse off of the outdoor equipment.
